# can't load launch images in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

the reason for this post is I can't load launch images in my iOS game.I have created images.xcassets and added the images in each selected devices resolutions (in the file inspector) just doing drag and drop, but I'm still getting a black launch screen.

I have is these images with these names:
in iphone 6 and prior (the bottom images)

astro320x480.png  -first one left- 
astroLaunch640x960@2x-1.png -middle one-
astroLaunch640x1136@2x-1.png -right one-

and int the top I have:
astroLaunch640x960@2x.png  -the left one-
astroLaunch640x1136@2x.png -the right one-

in the images names there's the images resolutions. I don't know if I have to use a special name or edit some file anywere but it isn't working that way, however with the app icon I not having any problem and I've done it the same way.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add launch images right click   and select **New Launch Image** , you should be able to see options to add Retina HD 4.7 , Retina HD 5.5 and Retina HD 5.5 landscape for iPhone6 and iPhone 6 plus . [More Details here](http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/09/10/iphone-6-plus-launch-image-adaptive-mode/)

[image: Image description]

Hope this helps.